# displaying only relevant posts

Tags: php, mysql, comments

I have a website that is made in php and mysql.

It is a podcast site which I have created.

The home page has a list of podcasts and once one is clicked it then brings up the episode.php?id= followed by the ID that is listed in mysql for that podcast.

at the bottom of the episodes page I have added a comment box.

and I have it to display the comments saved in mysql using:

```
<?php class feedback {
public function fetch_all(){
    global $pdo;
      $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments");
      $query->execute();
return $query->fetchAll();
              } }
$feedback = new feedback;
$articles = $feedback->fetch_all();
?>

<html>
<body>

    <?php foreach ($articles as $feedback) { ?>

<div class="comment" align="center">Name: <font size="3" color="grey"><?php echo $feedback['name']; ?></font> &nbsp;&nbsp; Email: <font size="3" color="grey">Hidden</font>
<br />
<font size="5" color="red"><div align="left"><?php echo $feedback['post']; ?></font></div></div>
<br><div class="divider2"> </div><br>
<?php } ?>
</html>
</body>
```

This displays all the comments that are listed in the comments field in mysql. 
each comment has a "cast" tab which displays the id of the podcast.

How can I get this to reflect the page being viewed?

for example.

**if I'm viewing episode.php?id=1 then I want the comments with the "cast" tab of "1" to be displayed and not the "cast" tab of "2". Also the same goes for episode.php?id=2. and so on!**

Please can someone guide me on how to do this?

thank you.

Kev

Comment: How about a `WHERE` in the query?

Comment: yes. I know about WHERE. but `     $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE cast = ?");
      $query->bindValue(1, $cast);` does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I had a little play around with this after trying Timo Dörsching's suggestion which did not work.

I hit undo to get it back to my original post and changed this:

```
<?php foreach ($articles as $feedback) { ?>

<div class="comment" align="center">Name: <font size="3" color="grey"><?php echo $feedback['name']; ?></font> &nbsp;&nbsp; Email: <font size="3" color="grey">Hidden</font>
<br />
<font size="5" color="red"><div align="left"><?php echo $feedback['post']; ?></font></div></div>
<br><div class="divider2"> </div><br>
<?php } ?>
```

to this:

```
    <?php foreach ($articles as $feedback) {
if ($feedback['cast'] === $_GET['id']) { ?>

<div class="comment" align="center">Name: <font size="3" color="grey"><?php echo $feedback['name']; ?></font> &nbsp;&nbsp; Email: <font size="3" color="grey">Hidden</font>
<br />
<font size="5" color="red"><div align="left"><?php echo $feedback['post']; ?></font></div></div>
<br><div class="divider2"> </div><br>
<?php } } ?>
```

this does the job perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

perhaps you have to filter the $_GET['id'] & $cast.... but this easy to google how to do this...
Have a look at: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

```
$cast = $_GET['id'];
public function fetch_all($cast){
    global $pdo;
      $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE cast/id/... = ".$cast."");
      $query->execute();
return $query->fetchAll();
              } }
$feedback = new feedback;
$articles = $feedback->fetch_all();
```